# Ошибка в строчках с break

Tags: javascript

```
do{
answer = prompt(getStatus() + ' [хотите карту ещё? 1 - да, иначе - нет'); //с помощью promt задаётся вопрос у игрока (выводится строчка)
if (answer == '1') { // если ответ 1,то продолжается игра и 
    player.push(getCard()); //  добавляется игроку карта 
}
alert(getStatus()); // показывается текущее состоянии игры
} while(answer == '1'); // должны ввести 1,чтоб продолжить игру
    sum = getSum(player); // получение суммы очков,сумма запоминается
    if (sum > 21) { // смотрим сумма больше 21
        alert('Перебор'+ getStatus()); // показывается перебор
        break; // break  выпроваживает нас из этого цикла и мы заканчиваем игру
    } else if (sum == 21) { // если нет перебора,но сумма равна 21
        alert('Black Jack!' + getStatus()); // то выводим блэк джек 
        break; // выводим из игры
    }
}
} else { // игрок закончил брать карты
         // теперь карты берёт дилер
         while (getSum(dealer) < 17) { // если сумма карт у дилера <17 
            dealer.push(getCard()); // функция pus добавляет ещё одну карту дилеру        
};
```

Пишет, что ошибка в строчке `break`.
Хром называет ошибку:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement

Но я не понимаю, что она обозначает. Может есть лёгкие способы, программы, которые доступно разъясняют, в чём именно заключается ошибка?

Comment: У вас эти break стоят уже после завершения закла `do ... while(answer == '1');` следовательно им не откуда выходить

Comment: @Mike, оформите в виде ответа :-)

Comment: @Grundy Да не, у нас ясновидцы есть, которые могут понять что хотел автор :)

Comment: @Mike, ну причина же правильно указана :-) так что, в этот раз у вас победа в конкурсе ясновидцев :-D

Comment: @Grundy Не, у MichaelPak гораздо лучше получается, он внес этот блок в цикл и еще от лишнего if избавился

Comment: @Mike ну так глубоко я не смотрел :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы запутались в фигурных скобках. Возможно, Вы хотели сделать так:

```
player.push(getCard());  // Игроку добавляется карта
alert(getStatus());  // Показывается текущее состоянии игры
player.push(getCard());
alert(getStatus());

answer = prompt(getStatus() + ' [хотите карту ещё? 1 - да, иначе - нет');   // С помощью promt задаётся вопрос у игрока (выводится строчка)

while (answer == '1') {  // Должны ввести 1,чтоб продолжить игру
    player.push(getCard());  

    alert(getStatus());  // Показывается текущее состоянии игры

    sum = getSum(player);  // Получение суммы очков, сумма запоминается
    if (sum > 21) {  // Смотрим, сумма больше 21
        alert('Перебор'+ getStatus());  // Показывается перебор
        break;  // Выпроваживает нас из этого цикла и мы заканчиваем игру
    } else if (sum == 21) {  // Если нет перебора,но сумма равна 21
        alert('Black Jack!' + getStatus());  // то выводим блэк джек 
        break;  // Выводим из игры
    }

    answer = prompt(getStatus() + ' [хотите карту ещё? 1 - да, иначе - нет');   // С помощью promt задаётся вопрос у игрока (выводится строчка)
}

// Проверка результата игрока
if (sum >= 21) {
    // Игра закончена
} else {  // Игрок закончил брать карты
    while (getSum(dealer) < 17) {  // Карты берёт дилер
        dealer.push(getCard());
    }
}
// Сравнение результатов игрока и дилера
```

Comment: @polin, насколько я знаю, в блекджеке игрок должен взять хотя бы одну карту. Поэтому надо взять одну карту и спросить, хочет ли игрок взять еще одну, до цикла и использовать цикл с предусловием, а не с постусловием.

Comment: @polin, исправил

Comment: полностью код игры написан,в вопрос я вставила только часть кода. Игра не работает,я хочу разобраться сама с каждой ошибкой,когда никак не справляюсь ,то обращаюсь сюда за помощью.